# Data entrytype fails to print title in ref list

Tags: biblatex

I am having some trouble in getting the data entry type to print a title in the reference list with biblatex-apa. The example from the test references seems to work fine, as well as when the entry type is changed to misc.

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,noextraspace,babel,american]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times-like font
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} % URL and TOC Handling
\usepackage{textcomp} % Copyright symbol
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents} % Insert/create new inline files
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@data{StatCan:2012,
  author      = {{Statistics Canada}},
  title       = {{O'Leary, Prince Edward Island} ({Code} 1103042) and {Lot 6, Prince Edward Island} ({Code} 1103041)},
  subtitle = {2011 {Census}},
  titleaddon = {Census profile},
  year        = {2012},
  type        = {Statistics Canada Catalogue no. 98-316-XWE},
  location    = {Ottawa, ON},
  URL         = {http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/dp-pd/prof/index.cfm?Lang=E},
}

@misc{StatCan:2012b,
  author      = {{Statistics Canada}},
  title       = {{O'Leary, Prince Edward Island} ({Code} 1103042) and {Lot 6, Prince Edward Island} ({Code} 1103041)},
  subtitle = {2011 {Census}},
  titleaddon = {Census profile},
  year        = {2012},
  type        = {Statistics Canada Catalogue no. 98-316-XWE},
  location    = {Ottawa, ON},
  URL         = {http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/dp-pd/prof/index.cfm?Lang=E},
}

% (APA 7.08 Example 54)
@DATA{7.08:54,
  ENTRYSUBTYPE   = {Data file and code book},
  AUTHOR         = {{Pew Hispanic Center}},
  TITLE          = {Changing Channels and Crisscrossing Cultures},
  SUBTITLE       = {A Survey of {L}atinos on the News Media},
  YEAR           = {2004},
  URL            = {http://pewhispanic.org/datasets/}
}

\end{filecontents} 


\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\title{Grand Unified Theory Revealed}
\author{Homer Jay Simspson}
\shorttitle{Grand Unified Theory}
\affiliation{Springfield University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I am using the report type field to show the catalogue number in its entirety, as a catalogue number does not seem to want show up otherwise under data.

Comment: Well, and what is the problem now? Can you add an screenshot what you get and mark there what you want?  Your question is not clear for me ...

Answer (score 1):

A look at the `data` driver in `apa.bbx` shows that it needs to have an `entrysubtype` field for the title to be printed (I'm not entirely sure why, but that's how it is currently set up).

The example `7.08:54`, you will find, has an `entrysubtype` field and so there the title is printed, but your `StatCan:201` is lacking such a field.
The easiest solution here is probably to move the contents of your `titleaddon` field to `entrysubtype`, since "Census profile" seems a very apt description of the kind of data you have here.

```
@data{StatCan:2012,
  author       = {{Statistics Canada}},
  title        = {{O'Leary, Prince Edward Island} ({Code} 1103042) and {Lot 6, Prince Edward Island} ({Code} 1103041)},
  subtitle     = {2011 {Census}},
  entrysubtype = {Census profile},
  year         = {2012},
  type         = {Statistics Canada Catalogue no. 98-316-XWE},
  location     = {Ottawa, ON},
  URL          = {http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/dp-pd/prof/index.cfm?Lang=E},
}
```

works just fine.